# Thymeleaf 3 (not) building layout sequentially?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I know about existance of layout dialect for Thymeleaf (https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect), but before jumping into said dialect dating pre thymeleaf 3, I wanted to explore newer fragment expressions (introduced in TL3).

So as per docs - I can define base.html that will work almost the same way that the layout dialect allows fragments to be managed.

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head th:fragment="base(title, links, content)">
        <title th:replace="${title}"></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/css/main.css" />
        <th:block th:replace="${links}"></th:block>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header th:replace="~{header :: header}"></header>
        <div th:replace="${content}"></div>
        <footer th:replace="~{footer::footer}"></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

...but then when I use this in my home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head th:replace="base::base(~{::title}, ~{::link}, ~{::content})">
        <title th:text="#{home.title}"></title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="test">
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="test1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="test2">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:fragment="content">
            <span>TEST CONTENT</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

...it acts like home.html only evaluates itself and arguments it passes to base.html because this is product:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>My home page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test"><link rel="stylesheet" href="test1"><link rel="stylesheet" href="test2">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span>TEST CONTENT</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, title is evaluated in home.html and passed to base.html, same goes for 3 links I provided in home.html. Also content gets passed and placed in proper place. What is missing? Everything that is not argument of base.html fragment. Thymeleaf ignores evaluating my header and footer and just removes them.

Let me just note that If I were to place header/footer in home.html inside content they will be evaluated like they should - from header.html with selector header: "~{header :: header}".

Am I missing something crucial as to how this whole thing is supposed to work? What's the point of being able to define fragments that will work as layout if they can't evaluate themselves and need everything passed from "child file (caller)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Xaltotun pointed out - I needed to fix my stuff.

I've placed base(args...) in header so my passed fragments werent visible in body, thus everything failed.

Let me just add some code:

Layout.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:fragment="layout(content, title, meta)">
<head>
<title th:text="${title}">Default Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/css/style.css" />
<th:block th:replace="${meta}" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="viewport">
        <header class="website-header">
            ...
        </header>

        <div th:replace="${content}"></div>

        <th:block th:replace="staticContentTemplate :: testFragment" />

        <footer class="website-footer">
            ...
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:replace="layout::layout(~{::content}, #{home.title}, ~{::meta})">
<head>
<th:block th:fragment="meta">
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="test">
</th:block>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:fragment="content">
        <span>TEST CONTENT</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Result is as expected:

- Home.html provides title, content and meta.
- Layout.html gives everything else, and also copies additional template from different source `staticContentTemplate :: testFragment`
- Tip for others: notice that I placed args in layout in this order - content since its always present, title that can be optional and meta that might not be needed - this allows us to call layout with just content: `layout(~{::content})` (shorter = better).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you mixed fragments and replacements together. The head replacement works well because you declared it correctly. But why did you declare a `th:replace` attribute in base.html like 
`<header th:replace="~{header :: header}"></header>`? It is not within a fragment, not a parameter, therefore it must be replaced from somewhere.

As far as I understand you expect fragments in base.html and replacements in home.html. Then make both the header and footer fragments and declare corresponding `th:replace` tags in home.html.

```
<div th:replace="${content}"></div>
```

This also doesn't work because it is not within a `th:fragment` tag. 
The bottom line: fix the hierarchy of tags and the logic of replacement.

Comment: Thanks to your post I realized that I placed base(args...) in <head> instead of <html>. Sadly I will report back in few days from now with anything more. Thanks (this will probably solve my issue).